# docker desktop windows 10 issue running RUN apk add openjdk17-jre. Same works on ubuntu

Tags: docker, compatibility, desktop

I have below Dockerfile,

```
FROM OURINTERNALREPO/xxxxx/alpine
USER root
RUN apk add --update
RUN apk add curl
RUN adduser -D -u 4001 appusr
RUN mkdir /app
RUN chown -R appusr:appusr /app
RUN apk add openjdk17-jre
USER appusr
WORKDIR /app
```

Above Dockerfile works perfect on ubuntu server when I do

> docker build -t testimage .

I recently procured docker desktop for windows and trying to build same Dockerfile with same command on windows 10 and I get below error,

```
 => ERROR [7/8] RUN apk add openjdk17-jre                                                                                                                                                                  28.7s
------
 > [7/8] RUN apk add openjdk17-jre:
#10 0.521 (1/25) Installing java-common (0.5-r0)
#10 5.526 ERROR: java-common-0.5-r0: temporary error (try again later)
#10 5.526 (2/25) Installing libffi (3.4.4-r0)
#10 10.53 (3/25) Installing p11-kit (0.24.1-r1)
#10 10.53 ERROR: libffi-3.4.4-r0: temporary error (try again later)
#10 12.51 (4/25) Installing libtasn1 (4.19.0-r0)
#10 12.56 (5/25) Installing p11-kit-trust (0.24.1-r1)
#10 12.73 (6/25) Installing java-cacerts (1.0-r1)
#10 12.85 (7/25) Installing openjdk17-jre-headless (17.0.6_p10-r0)
#10 26.62 (8/25) Installing libxau (1.0.10-r0)
#10 26.65 (9/25) Installing libmd (1.0.4-r0)
#10 26.69 (10/25) Installing libbsd (0.11.7-r0)
#10 26.73 (11/25) Installing libxdmcp (1.1.4-r0)
#10 26.76 (12/25) Installing libxcb (1.15-r0)
#10 26.84 (13/25) Installing libx11 (1.8.4-r0)
#10 27.09 (14/25) Installing libxext (1.3.5-r0)
#10 27.14 (15/25) Installing libxi (1.8-r0)
#10 27.18 (16/25) Installing libxrender (0.9.11-r0)
#10 27.22 (17/25) Installing libxtst (1.2.4-r0)
#10 27.26 (18/25) Installing alsa-lib (1.2.8-r0)
#10 27.39 (19/25) Installing libbz2 (1.0.8-r4)
#10 27.50 (20/25) Installing libpng (1.6.38-r0)
#10 27.56 (21/25) Installing freetype (2.12.1-r0)
#10 27.67 (22/25) Installing giflib (5.2.1-r2)
#10 27.73 (23/25) Installing libjpeg-turbo (2.1.4-r0)
#10 27.84 (24/25) Installing lcms2 (2.14-r0)
#10 27.98 (25/25) Installing openjdk17-jre (17.0.6_p10-r0)
#10 28.32 Executing busybox-1.35.0-r29.trigger
#10 28.32 Executing ca-certificates-20220614-r4.trigger
#10 28.39 2 errors; 203 MiB in 43 packages
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add openjdk17-jre]: exit code: 2
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What dns server entries do you have in `daemon.json` (located under `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` in Windows)?

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Docker\config>type daemon.json
{
  "experimental": false,
  "hosts": [
    "npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine_windows"
  ]
}

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share how your problem is related to programming

Comment: You can explicitly specify the dns server in the `daemon.json` by adding `"dns": ["8.8.8.8"]` (you can also do this with docker desktop under docker engine I think). After that you need to restart the docker service

Comment: Thank you, adding "dns": ["8.8.8.8"] resolved the issue.